How to make anchor's underline span text-overflow width?
I have a set of links that need to be truncated. I know that text.overflow: elipsis on anchors can be troublesome, but here's my question:
How can I make anchor text-decoration: underline follow the width of the truncated anchor?
As you can see, the three dots are positioned outside the link underline.
I also tried to add the truncation to the inner span of each link, but it makes the link's underline disappear.
How can I solve this?


a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><span class="link-text">Menu item</span></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><span class="link-text">Very long menu item that needs to be truncated</span></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><span class="link-text">Menu item</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>




put a border at the bottom and use max-width instead of width

@tacoshy Interesting. How do you mean?

@Paulie_D That one works well for me with a few tweaks. Plase make it an answer.

You can simply add a border-bottom to the anchor. However you should use max-width instead of width so the border does nto streatch to the full 150px in every case.


a {
  text-decoration: none;
  max-width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><span class="link-text">Menu item</span></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><span class="link-text">Very long menu item that needs to be truncated</span></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><span class="link-text">Menu item</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>




A pseudo-element on the span, suitable positioned, would not be a complete replacement for text-decoration but it would be a functional equivalent.


a {
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-bottom: .05em;
}

span {
  position: relative;
}

span:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0em;
  left: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><span class="link-text">Menu item</span></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><span class="link-text">Very long menu item that needs to be truncated</span></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><span class="link-text">Menu item</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>



